# Input not read correctly, rock paper scissors lizard spock

Tags: python

as my homework (using codeskulptor.org) I put together a simple Rock-Paper-Scissors-Lizard-Spock 'game' in Python, where hard coded player's guesses were running the programme. Translation from name to number and other way round, random computer choice and printing... everything worked fine.

Then I tried to introduce input so that player gets to type their guess. However, the console prints only the log about wrong input but doesn't launch the rest of the programme if the input is actually correct... Tried various modifications, but I'm stuck... am I missing something obvious? Thanks!

```
import simplegui
import random

def get_guess(guess):

    if guess == "rock":
        return 0
    elif guess == "Spock":
        return 1
    elif guess == "paper":
        return 2
    elif guess == "lizard":
        return 3
    elif guess == "scissors":
        return 4
    else:
        print "Error guess_to_number:", guess, "is not a rpsls-element"
        return


def number_to_name(number):

    if number == 0:
        return "rock"
    elif number == 1:
        return "Spock"
    elif number == 2:
        return "paper"
    elif number == 3:
        return "lizard"
    elif number == 4:
        return "scissors"
    else:
        print "Error number_to_name:", number, "is not in [0, 4]"
        return


def rpsls(guess): 

    print
    print "Player chooses", guess
    player_number = get_guess(guess)

    computer_number = random.randrange(5)
    computer_choice = number_to_name(computer_number)
    print "Computer chooses", computer_choice

    diff_mod = (player_number - computer_number) % 5
    if diff_mod == 0:
        print "Player and computer tie!"
    elif diff_mod == 1 or diff_mod == 2:
        print "Player wins!"
    else:
        print "Computer wins!"

frame = simplegui.create_frame("GUI-based RPSLS", 200, 200)
frame.add_input("Enter guess for RPSLS", get_guess, 200)

frame.start()
```

Comment: make sure to post your code w/ correct indentation. that might be very relevant to your question!

Comment: Yes,thanks, I did have issues with indenting the code here... it's also there: http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user42_2nel7DJswmoJyan.py
could you point me in some direction?

Comment: I got rid of the `simplegui` business and just got the guesses using `guess = input("Input guess: ")` then running `rpsls(guess)` and it worked fine. Seems like the issue might be with simplegui in particular.